# How to sign digital signature with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, certificate, digital-signature

I am working with selenium to automate the website filling tasks. However, users can log in to the website only using the `.p12` certificate by choosing. So when I press "log in with digital signature", it automatically opens the software that converts the `.p12` file into XML and sends data to the website. Is it possible to do the same process completely in python without using any other external software/applications?

Answer (score 2):

If you want try using Registry Editor and use ChromeDriver try:

1-) Press Windwos + R and type it "regedit".

2-) Rigth Click in "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies", select new -> Key and put the name "Google", then into this key add key "Chrome" and into this one add outher key called "AutoSelectCertificateForUrls". The full path need to be this "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls".

3-) Rigth click on AutoSelectCertificateForUrls, new -> String Value, and put the name "1".

4-) Rigth click on "1", modified then copy and paste this JSON "{"pattern":"https://urlFromTheSiteYouWantAccess","filter":{"ISSUER":{"CN":"your cn"},"SUBJECT":{"CN":"your certificate cn"}}}".

I edit the answer because I made the mistake to put here a example of Java. Sorry for that Uldana Duisenaly.
But now i will input a code for python change end access a web site with python and selenium.
Don´t forget to run the app as administrator.
The imports.

```py
from os import times
import winreg
from OpenSSL import crypto
from selenium import webdriver
```

**The method to Open a certificate:**

```py
def GetCertificate(pathOfCertificate, passwordOfCertifcate):
    pkcs12 = crypto.load_pkcs12(open(pathOfCertificate, 'rb').read(), passwordOfCertifcate)   
    return pkcs12.get_certificate()
```

**The method to update the Json in StringValue in regitry key "AutoSelectCertificateForUrls":**

```py
def UpdateStringValue(strigValueName,newValueOfStrinValue, stringValuePath):
  key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, stringValuePath, 0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
  winreg.SetValueEx(key, strigValueName, 0, winreg.REG_SZ, newValueOfStrinValue)
  winreg.CloseKey(key)
```

**The main where I declaring 2 varibles for path where is the string value and the name of string value. In my case is "1":**

```py
pathOfstringValue = 'SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls'
stringValueName = '1'
```

**Get the certificate and the informations of Issuer and Subject:**

```py
certificate = GetCertificate("C:\yourCrtificatePath\\Certificate.pfx", 'certificatePassword')
subject = certificate.get_subject()
issuer = certificate.get_issuer()
```

**The Urls the firth is where the certificate will be send and the other is the page where we have the button to login with certicate:**

```py
url_where_certificate_will_be_send = "https://notacarioca.rio.gov.br/"
url = 'https://notacarioca.rio.gov.br/senhaweb/login.aspx'
```

**Building the json, (sorry for the ugly way to handling with the string) and calling the method to edit the string value registry:**

```py
json = '{"pattern":"' + url_where_certificate_will_be_send + '","filter":{"ISSUER":{"CN":"' + issuer.CN + '","C":"' + issuer.C + '","O":"' + issuer.O + '"},"SUBJECT":{"CN":"' + subject.CN + '","C":"' + subject.C + '","O":"' + subject.O + '"}}}'
UpdateStringValue(stringValueName, json, pathOfstringValue)
```

**And finally the code to click the button for login with certificate:**

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url)

btn_certificate_login = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_cphCabMenu_imgLoginICP')
btn_certificate_login.click()
times.sleep(2.4)
driver.quit()
```

For download the code visit my github [here](https://github.com/JimmyelsonSilvaPeres/PythonLoginWithCertificateSelenium/tree/main)

Answer (score 0):

One word answer is No.

I suppose you are trying to do web scratching using selenium and want to automate login using Digital Certificate.  Browsers run in system sandbox and can't access system resources without help of any other external software.

[PKI Web Authentication using Digital Certificate and Browser Extension](https://web.signer.digital/home) sample I have developed; also has native messaging host running under hood, which provides access to system Certificate Store (or Smartcard).  Though, it can also handle the things silently without opening Certificate Selection pop-up, external component viz. Browser Extension and Native Host is required.